# order of execution of getChildHtml() inside .phtml file

Tags: magento2, layout, template, phtml

I have the following in a layout file:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="scratch.customer" as="customer" template="Binayak_ScratchMod::html/customer.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
           template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</block>
```

The corresponding *customer.phtml* file is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <div  class="customer-menu">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I am expecting the output to be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="customer-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/customer/account/">My Account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
                <a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/customer/account/logout/" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/magento\/customer\/account\/logout\/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvLw,,&quot;}}">
                    Sign Out    
                </a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="customer-menu">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/customer/account/">My Account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento/customer/account/logout/" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/magento\/customer\/account\/logout\/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvLw,,&quot;}}">
            Sign Out    
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can any one explain why?

**Additional info:**

The parent block of `scratch.customer` is:

```
<container name="scratch.navbar.wrapper" label="Scratch Navbar wrapper" htmlTag="nav" htmlClass="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <block class="Binayak\ScratchMod\Block\Html\Navbar" name="scratch.navbar" before="-" template="html/navbar.phtml" ttl="3600">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="scratch.minicart" as="minicart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>

        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="scratch.customer" as="customer-menu" template="Binayak_ScratchMod::html/customer.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link" as="customer-menu-account">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link" as="customer-menu-register">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link" as="customer-menu-auth"
                       template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
</container>
```

And the corresponding `navbar.phtml` file looks like this:

```
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml() ?>

<div class="navigation-overlay">
  <div class="container-fluid relative">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-toggle-wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>        
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo-container">
          <div class="logo-wrap local-scroll">

            <?php if ($block->isHomePage()):?>
                <a class="logo" href="#" title="Aadikara" >
            <?php else: ?>
                <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>" title="Aadikara">
            <?php endif ?>
                    <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>"
                         alt="Aadikara"
                    />
                </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->

      <div class="menu-socials">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('customer'); ?>
          </li>
          <li>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart'); ?>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav local-scroll text-right">

            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end col -->


    </div> <!-- end row -->
  </div> <!-- end container -->
</div> <!-- end navigation -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you try to call the getChildHtml with the name's block

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('my-account-link');?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('register-link');?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('authorization-link');?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
```

also please check your phtml for any unclosed element or typo.

Comment: Calling `$block->getChildHtml() ` with no arguments will all child blocks' templates, I guess in order they are placed in layout.

Comment: I have tried calling `$block->getChildHtml()` with arguments, the result is the same. I have checked for typos also. And if I use a simple echo statement instead `<?php echo "hello"?>` then that works fine.

Comment: Maybe you share also the parent block of "scratch.customer"?

Comment: @NikoK I have included the parent block and its corresponding  .phtml file in my question.

Comment: @NikoK turns out you were right. If you put a `<div>` element inside a `<li>` tag then chrome fails to handle that. So it was in fact a html formatting issue.

Comment: Remember, if a block has an alias, getChildHtml() should be called with it, not the block's name